# The definite article before a noun, if another noun + a numeral are present before as an identifier?

Tags: definite-articles

I know that one may not use the definite article before "noun + numeral" constructs, like "floor six", "room twenty five" etc.

But should it be used in constructs where "noun + numeral" are like an identifier or name, for instance:

(the) "block 6" item, (the) CSS 2.2 specification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because you are talking about **the** item.  You wouldn't say **the** six unless there were more than one choice of six.  You might take the floor six stairs to get to floor six.